# Query to retreive data having Data = '1753/01/01'

Tags: sql

I want to retrieve those records which have Data <= paramdate and also those records which have Date = '1753/01/01'

Thanks

Comment: Your almost there. Just write your conditions in the WHERE clause. (OR them together.)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

you could use DATEDIFF

DATEDIFF will return different time, day, month, pr year, based what you want to compare.
Example :

```
`DATEDIFF (DAY, '01/01/2017', '02/01/2017')`
```

This will return 1, as the comparation is the day. 
Note : datediff also could return negative value, as the position which is higher. Example :

```
'DATEDIFF (DAY, '02/01/2017', '01/01/2017')'
```

will return -1

When you want to get the data that the date and the format are specified , you could use **CONVERT** to convert it to your formatted date and compare it like usual

Example :

```
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, '2017/01/01', 103) = '01/01/2017'
```